# On Parse.com, why is my Object Save in CloudCode not executing? Or am I being an idiot?

Tags: parse-platform

Probably I'm an idiot. Here's the code:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/98022f8febeec13db113

I'm creating a Stripe charge in CloudCode, and upon success saving a Parse Object, and upon success of that, updating an existing Parse object with a link to the first object.

The first Parse Object gets created and saved, but I never see the Console.log(line 17) telling me it did. The second, nested object doesn't get saved, and I don't see any success/fail logs for that one either.

Anything pop out as to why I don't ever see the console output line 17 of the linked gist? The object gets saved so it should call the success function.

I should add that I can run this code client side and it works fine. CloudCode seems to not like it for some reason.

Anything stick out to you as to why this is not working?

Comment: First, I suggest using Promises instead of nesting "success" blocks. IMHO it's a lot easier to follow the code. When you uncomment line 10, does the log message appear?

Comment: I will check that- thanks again for your help Trees. I think I may have had some CloudCode that was interfering with this operation. Will get back. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks again- the response.success was being called before everything could happen. It should have been nested in the innermost success callback function.